# snowflake connector SQL compilation error: maximum number of expressions in a list exceeded, expected at most 16,384

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to insert data with Python from SQL Server to Snowflake table. It works in general, but if I want to insert a bigger chunk of data, it gives me an error:

snowflake connector SQL compilation error: maximum number of expressions in a list exceeded, expected at most 16,384

I'm using snowflake connector for Python. So, it works if you want to insert 16384 rows at once. My table has over a million records. I don't want to use csv files.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to insert > 16k recs using sqlalchemy and pandas as:

```
pandas_df.to_sql(sf_table, con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append', chunksize=16000)
```

where engine is sqlalchemy.create_engine(...)

Comment: True, but if you need to insert more than a million records, it’ll take much time. I’ve recently found the solution: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#label-python-connector-api-write-pandas

Comment: It's from here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#label-python-connector-api-write-pandas

Comment: @Maranax can you give an example on the solution you provided? I looked at the docs but still unclear how to leverage this solution.

Comment: @mikelowry Roughly it's like that: import pandas as pd
import snowflake as sf
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas
import sys  #Connect with Python connector
conn = sf.connector.connect(
    user=user,
    password=password,
    account=account,
    database=DB,
    schema=SCHEMA,
    warehouse=WH,
    role=ROLE,
    format=FMT
) #and the main part is: Cnt = md.GetTableCount(SchemaName, TableName, StartDate, EndDate)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the ideal way to load data into Snowflake, but since you specified that you didn't want to create CSV files, you could look into loading the data into a panda dataframe and then use the `write_pandas` function in the python connector, which will (behind the scenes) leverage a flat file and a `COPY INTO` statement, which is the fastest way to get data into Snowflake.  This issue with this method will likely be that pandas requires a lot of memory on the machine you are running the script on.  There is a `chunk_size` parameter, though, so you can control it with that.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#write_pandas

Comment: Thank you, Mike. I've tried it. It gives me another error, but I think it's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For Whoever is facing that problem, find below a complete solution to connect and to insert data into Snowflake using Sqlalchemy.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

snowflake_username = 'username'
snowflake_password = 'password'
snowflake_account = 'accountname'
snowflake_warehouse = 'warehouse_name'
snowflake_database = 'database_name'
snowflake_schema = 'public'


engine = create_engine(
    'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/{db}/{schema}?warehouse={warehouse}'.format(
        user=snowflake_username,
        password=snowflake_password,
        account=snowflake_account,
        db=snowflake_database,
        schema=snowflake_schema,
        warehouse=snowflake_warehouse,
        ),echo_pool=True, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20
    )

try:
    connection = engine.connect()
    results = connection.execute('select current_version()').fetchone()
    print(results[0])
    df.columns = map(str.upper, df_sensor.columns)
    df.to_sql('table'.lower(), con=connection, schema='amostraschema', index=False, if_exists='append', chunksize=16000)
    
finally:
    connection.close()
    engine.dispose()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the executemany with server side binding. This will create files in a staging area and will allow you to insert more than 16384 rows.

```
con =  snowflake.connector.connect(
        account='',
        user = '',
        password = '',
        dbname='',
        paramstyle = 'qmark')
 
sql = "insert into tablename (col1, col2) values (?, ?)"
 
rows = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
 
con.cursor().executemany(sql, rows)
```

See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#label-python-connector-binding-batch-inserts for more details

Note: This will not work with client side binding, the %s format.